# download weblogic install package from oracle website via curl

Tags: curl, download

I'd like to download the installation package from the oracle website (as a part of my CI build). So requirement is to have it done without any user interaction, using the linux command line toolset.

I've tried the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ORCL_USER='top'
ORCL_PWD='secret'
rm -rf cookies.txt

curl -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-weblogicserver-cookie" -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -L -v http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/12212/fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip
curl -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-weblogicserver-cookie" --data "sso_username=${ORCL_USER}&ssopassword=${ORCL_PWD}&v=v1.4&locale=&" -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -L -v https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp
```

(where ORCL_USER and ORCL_PWD are replaced with valid values)

However after 2.nd curl command I end up with response like this:

```
...
<div class="cb41 cb41v0">
<input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="">
<div class="cb41w1">
<span id="errormsg" class="error-show">
Error! Do not use bookmarked URL. Please type the URL you are trying to reach directly into your browser.
</span>
```

...

Any ideas on how to proceed/what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI used to signin is `https://login.oracle.com/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit` and it seems it needs an additional parameter `OAM_REQ` when you perform your authentication in addition to `ssousername` and `password`

When you request this page :
    http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/12212/fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip

You go through 2 `302`moved page + the last one which is the one that redirect you to the signin page. But the redirection is done via Javascript eg :

```
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_self">
</head>

<body onLoad="document.myForm.submit()">
    <noscript>
        <p>JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.</p>
    </noscript>
    <form action="https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp" method="post" name="myForm">
        <!------------ DO NOT REMOVE ------------->
        <!----- loginform renderBrowserView ------>
        <!-- Required for SmartView Integration -->
        <input type="hidden" name="contextType" value="external">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="string">
        <input type="hidden" name="contextValue" value="%2Foam">
        <input type="hidden" name="challenge_url" value="https%3A%2F%2Flogin.oracle.com%2Fmysso%2Fsignon.jsp">
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="sercure_string">
        <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="7632874198179980871">
        <input type="hidden" name="authn_try_count" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="site2pstoretoken" value="v1.2~CA55CD32~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
        <input type="hidden" name="v" value="v1.4">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_submit_url" value="https://login.oracle.com:443/sso/auth">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_cancel_url" value="https://edelivery.oracle.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_error_code" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="ssousername" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="subscribername" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="OAM_REQ" value="VERSION_4~7fNDjTUHJ%2bWv7qhZS3Txgx0QbxQGs3AJ4pzB6vtcD0tVSis7wBsyHhsbVWQ0C6Bpms498sJoLqqL9wsGpepsxy2wEt%2f2bLsbWZNzKtq2HbPKjkw0cImi2nmhhS%2bUq4mRZKlX2qNcCPaXjqBFN4NCs388sUIaues2CWPuDv8P%2fpnQHvLoMsu10H%2fO8WDb4o3AI4afso7D3UQdtgj5P%2fd8AKt0Gsfn9opFX88tW8B%2bQhk%2fGvYjKcVPDiVoTpkviOf1m4VCpEVTmvXHMbiDWt9NTpTSWQBIplLB%2fqgvgowdGp%2f51GKATLfmtH0ocaX7OYX9vCc5%2fcfnNvuWWHBtnsNSZPUb39SJwlWpTIHnCAAAblQfKeLZcu6a9xueyiep2S7bT7itdXuFKtPZdVKnAm%2fG8Ngy%2fy25s4DdSUFWiDg2atnaWuim8eOkjih2PCVQ2w0P40FKrB3oQYsQW1vdIsy0Twa%2bJQykOUni6qvGW%2bfJXpmN6kLklI1YT5uzL2%2bcUEv0M5ZAIvdiJYtsgjgE3snm8N9UE4OcPXhOZwu0Vriib%2bOqPNGFuSEeJMnDkzakmQJjEckUPG4K%2bIKWShwPrQ76PqHrcOFUO0VED2%2frlrOCik1gsDRYhzm6n1ptLw3YiHbXs0bmxKA81240y%2fVYAMx9JOs%2bbii4SdMuWKO3%2f%2b%2fXFddc56pNjioxbq3wVUGUrQn7fBjGVqkEtGR2xpG4nQ%2bsLiXdOfEPYLsFw90BmGh%2fvn2DPdiImfGOXP%2ffaCCGH%2fpZCyLuQP%2fucbOAPtSrSUK3OuQv2OJfc6YApnToooboVK0%2fXKpgYzsd6pK4nwHXt0l5p77HoFByFYaLV6zxXGrtyhk7PUpyAW3Zz6fKjNH7b22AOH%2fuvgAW5CyP8hpSe1EBQoUGGI9p4l5qW6aL9vkpsi2IxqT1EenoOE4M2baf8WR6Ok%2fisCBhFxz%2bloC2SYLL1jzYoUXGxr5RfdzdsduGLA62XLAhs8A6T7%2fWOJU9WOKaf3KT9DXSsIzW6OMIyhAFJ%2buW%2fq2PVlXMz%2feZEc2lIsF%2fqpbaRsH3e81cvmizcWc%2bWdq5eT0hJnxoOhS56xUoGzr8vqD7IUu%2fkN2fGVf8xpuIiSio1K54Y2ti03%2fR62ZfGgxx9T5b8DDbKBRvv8Dw9W8dPGja%2b0gp3K4uVcjppk886OfOGBUGYFG0txQF55an7744%2f3Q%2fMzqZ7k1MSKvPzmekTzfAokih8kghGazgU9XByI0X%2bqNCcTJEVRdWUIoOBSIsmeliowTZYd9jfCotWwgoD09%2b%2bRfPgcpWYpfi7gjfHqFQ3BOsYTk4Tn7WJoJGxpcRCv%2fQPneJR%2fdMx38JrFFRmwBbhdQmYGUj7Og2zafOW7MDFGsaHk%2buBsrV1A8FTTOmTFxhpygM0krHSnKp0Bb6G%2b0UOHzQ8Jyz0HzVuEsgZoM%2fPMWAg9owaLfyLXFoXvmgy6abmB9%2bWB3PG7If%2bYXnLdEO36F3SGsevEOn5jHERsm5YVBy1UZdJRUNSIQssmq0eogh7uJjGOWyrBTLHeRjW49UCHTa2rIXrbL8S5XkLDnLNtIVc6fNPis41MvpY0zAbxWmy0ngZkBem61jBTrtOIE%2bG0qzdGItSJ0uq9NAZkX6XSKK%2fRjr1xle9duYYc10XL52pABawwXSgSFp3vU43p7xyNPpFwB28D7rKPvOBd2QJJ3a2Ct3bjYpzw7vA%2bUjoKhjPmWcJaGR2KLEVtjKhK0EMWJSwVaG4furgKgOEEKDs9eXutEMqYVthI3qmnbfba3rIcc7%2bLfvMhxSGrkhTGMCeUN3vhplFPa1BcGLwQC2J8SHgJiopKVmPdjXe6lpSodvxBL8PWH3rm0n%2fzsQi6mWidK10AVghPGdjEsOY%2bddZpHrhQZuYLyNaa%2ba8oGlWBJHNUVj14hwwB4x7DEOXCpDiepV%2bs4fswcSYr6gWPo%2b9%2bteCq6PkyHA%2f3dTUnuNRfKw31Zy7mik5Pr3Ta6mYmIS1NiAlk3A4ua%2bFe%2bdwbgB7ZmdDrdzs%2fWp38%2b3x5iIME5j0ks0dJFuFg1BquyhvHIDhdfGDINmJYW3%2fVjkpL10otYcFU66e21mWbPtEcsEPfSvAUlFI
```

So basically you just have to request the file page, store cookies and parse this `OAM_REQ` parameter. Then, the right URI to `POST` the credentials is `https://login.oracle.com/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit`.

Note :

- you need the cookie `s_cc=true;` in addition to `oraclelicense=accept-weblogicserver-cookie;` to validate the license
- Oracle seems to have blocked `curl` user-agent, use another one

The following script uses `curl` to perform http requests and [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to parse the `OAM_REQ` variable from html :

```sh
username="your_username"
password="your_password"

rm -f cookies.txt

# store the OAM_REQ parameter
oam_req=$(curl -s -L -c cookies.txt "http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/12212/fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip" \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' | \
     pup 'form [name="OAM_REQ"] attr{value}')

# download the file with the additionnal OAM_REQ parameter
curl -o "weblogic.zip" -L -b cookies.txt 'https://login.oracle.com/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit' \
    -H 'Cookie: s_cc=true; oraclelicense=accept-weblogicserver-cookie;' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' \
    --data-urlencode "ssousername=$username" --data-urlencode "password=$password" -d "OAM_REQ=$oam_req" --compressed
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, however I get saved in `weblogic.zip` html error page with text: `System error. Please re-try your action. If you continue to get this error, please contact the Administrator.`

Comment: regarding your URL encoding hint, I just went for: `--data-urlencode` instead of `-d` curl argument

Comment: Yes, you can use `--data-url-encode` directly for the username & password, see my updated post

Answer (score 1):

based on the @Bertrand answer I introduced the github project: https://github.com/typekpb/oradown

```
Usage: oradown.sh [OPTION]... URL
oradown enables download of the SSO protected files (specified by URL) from the Oracle website.

Functional arguments:
  -C, --cookie=LICENSE_COOKIE  name of the license cookie (mandatory)
  -O, --output=FILE            output FILE (optional)
  -P, --password=PASSWORD      set the Oracle PASSWORD (mandatory)
  -U, --username=USERNAME      set the Oracle USERNAME (mandatory)

Logging and info arguments:
  -H, --help                   print this help and exit
  -V, --version                display the version of oradown and exit.

Examples:

  Downloads weblogic 12c (oradown downloaded via wget):
    wget -O - -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typekpb/oradown/master/oradown.sh  | \
    bash -s -- --cookie=accept-weblogicserver-server \
        --username=foo --password=bar \
        http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/12212/fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip

    Downloads weblogic 12c (oradown downloaded via curl):
    curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typekpb/oradown/master/oradown.sh  | \
    bash -s -- --cookie=accept-weblogicserver-server \
        --username=foo --password=bar \
        http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/12212/fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip
```